# Sporadic disk clicking sound

Tags: linux, hard-drive, clicking-sound

I'm having some unusual and sporadic hard disk clicking issues. Here is a cronological description of the facts.

I'm using an **ASUS P6T-SE** with Intel Core i7, 6Gb RAM 600W Power supply and ATI4670 graphics, running Ubuntu 10.10.

About one month ago my hard disk (**SATA II Seagate Barracuda 1Tb 7200 rpm**) started making a clicking sound: a sort of loud tic-tac, every second or so, when involved in disk activity. The system was clearly slower than before at disk access, but it was functional and I could not find any signal of trouble on the linux logs. I disconnected the disk and tried an older SATA drive I had around: no problem with it. Then I reconnected the Seagate disk, and the problem was mysteriously gone. Ubuntu booted normally, usual speed, no clicking.

A couple of weeks later, the problem reappeared. I tried disconnecting reconnecting (as it somehow solved the problem before) without luck. So, despite it was a rather new drive, I assumed it was a hardware issue, made backups and bought a new drive.

The new drive is a **SATA II Seagate Barracuda 1.5 Tb 7200 rpm**. I installed both drives at the same time, with the intention of transferring my files from on to the other. To my surprise, when I booted the computer with both drives, **both** started making the clicking sound !! Even worse, I removed the old drive, leaving the unformated new drive connected, and booted from a LiveCD. It kept clicking !

Puzzled by this, I tried both drives on my laptop with a SATA to USB cable. At the moment I connected any of them, they made one or two unusual clicks and immediately stopped doing that and worked normally. The old drive I thought almost dead, was working like a charm as if nothing happened.

Then I thought: "ok, it must be the motherboard. Let's try again". So, I reconnected the old drive to the ASUS P6T motherboard (the same cables and SATA port as before), and it worked as if nothing happened ! The problem was gone again. The new 1.5 Tb drive was also working ok: No clicking nor slowdown.

So I left the old 1Tb disk connected and kept using the computer daily during 3 weeks, until today it happened again. Now I don't really know what to do or check. I'm not even sure if it is a hardware issue any more !

This is rather annoying as it seems it happens with a period of 2 or 3 weeks and I have no means of forcing it to happen. Does anyone have a clue of what can causes this behaviour or have any suggestions of things I should check when it happens again ?

What I did today is checking some SMART parameters

- Error log: `smartctl -l error /dev/sda`. No errors
- Short selftest: `smartctl -t short /dev/sda`. No errors
- Disk Health check: `smartctl -H /dev/sda`. passed

And here are the vendor specific parameters (`smartctl -A /dev/sda`) Which I'm not quite sure how to interpret.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   120   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       235962588
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       187
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   072   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       16348045
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3590
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       94
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
```

Comment: Why does your drive not report parameter 193?

Comment: No idea. What does this parameter tell ?

Comment: I think 193 is load cycles - how many times the heads have been loaded.  If it's abnormally high the heads might be wearing out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the Advanced Power Management to OFF?

```
hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda
```

You can check your current setting with:

```
hdparm -B /dev/sda
```